# How to show percentage values from a poll as static progressbars?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview

What is the best way of showing poll results in percentage as a progress bar like view? 
[image]

In addition, this control is a listview, with the above case having 3 items.

EDIT: As a newbie, the information below is slightly complicated for me to follow.

I've added a row layout to this. Since the percentage values will come at runtime (sorry for not mentioning that before), I've modified the weight parameter of the View.

However, nothing is working to show the bars as expected. Do I need to provide more information for this?

Also, are there any other ways to solve this problem?

Answer (score -1):

The "*best*" way is something that can always be debated. The simplest way would be to just create your own view and handle the drawing of the correct width. However, depending on what you're after, you could actually do it with simple understanding of weights, specifically `weightSum` and `layout_weight`

**The result:**
[image]

**The code:**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="40dp">

    <LinearLayout android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:weightSum="100">

        <View android:layout_height="fill_parent"
              android:layout_width="0dp"
              android:background="#F00"
              android:layout_weight="56"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="YES 56%"
        android:gravity="center_vertical" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

By specifying the total weight available we can achieve the drawing of a  view that will take n% of the available width/height. This will work with any view, with complex drawables and whatnot

**Update** If this is inside a `ListView` the layout should be the one used for each row, and simply set the `layout_weight` on your adapter.